# Intercambiar posiciones de un string que representan coordenadas de una geometría (intercambiar coordenadas))

Tags: javascript, string

Tengo un string similar a este:

```
String var1 = "[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],[x4,y4],...,[xn,yn]]"
```

y quiero intercambiar la posición de todas las x con las y para que me quede como resultado algo así:

```
String var1 = "[[y1,x1],[y2,x2],[y3,x3],[y4,x4],...,[yn,xn]]"
```

¿puede álguien proporcionarme un código que haga esto?

Este es el código que estoy probando y no me funciona:

```
var coordinatesAux1 = JSON.parse(coordinates.replace(/"/g));

var coordinatesAux2 = coordinatesAux1.map(row=>row.reverse()).reverse();
                    
coordinates = JSON.stringify(coordinatesAux2);
```

Comment: This is [es.SO]. Please translate your question to spanish, otherwise your question can be closed

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Presiona [edit] y agrega el código que has intentado.

Comment: Ya está agrgado

Comment: ¿Es javascript o java? Por favor, utiliza correctamente las etiquetas. El primer código que adjuntas es código de java ¿y luego tu "intento" de solución lo pones en javascript? No queda nada claro qué es lo que quieres.

Comment: Es js. El primer código era simplemente para explicar como quiero que sea la transformación. En el segundo código, coordinates es el string que quiero modificar.

Comment: @DavidGarcia93 A simple vista, para obtener lo que buscas, te estaría sobrando un `reverse`, es decir, tu código debería ser `coordinatesAux1.map(row=>row.reverse())`

Comment: Cualquier de las respuestas que te han dado, sirve siempre y cuando sepas cómo convertir ese string en un array. Lectura obligatoria: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 1):

Qué gusto ver que estás intentando hacerlo.
Si utilizas Javascritp puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
const coordenadas = [["x1","y1"],["x2","y2"],["x3","y3"]]
const coordenadasYX = coordenadas.map( item =>{
  let newItem = []
  newItem.push(item[1])
  newItem.push(item[0])
  return newItem
})

console.log(coordenadasYX)
```

En la constante coordenadasYX están almacenadas en el orden que necesitas.
Espero te sirva

Ahora bien, si lo que tienes es sun string y no un array, primero debes convertirlo a un array para poder trabajarlo y al final, puedes quitarle las comillas.

Podría esr algo como esto:

```js
const originalString = "[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],[x4,y4]]"
const trimmed = originalString.substring(2,originalString.length-2)
const array = trimmed.split("],[")


let finalList = array.map(item=>{
  const coordenates = item.split(",")
  let newItem = []
  newItem.push(coordenates[1])
  newItem.push(coordenates[0])
  return newItem
})

const finalString = JSON.stringify(finalList).replaceAll(/['"]+/g, '')
console.log(originalString)
console.log(finalString)
```

Comment: No me sirve porque yo no tengo un array de strings, lo que tengo es un string:          
"[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],[x4,y4],...,[xn,yn]]"

Comment: Y que hay dentro de cada una de las posiciones de los arrays?

Comment: Agregué a la respuesta como hacerlo a partir de un string.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías intentar algo como lo siguiente: (Esta opción no modifica el array original y devuelve un nuevo array con el órden deseado)

```
const coordenadas = [["x1","y1"],["x2","y2"],["x3","y3"],["x4","y4"]]
const coordenadasInvertidas = array1.map(item=>[...item].reverse())
```

---

También podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
const coordenadas = [["x1","y1"],["x2","y2"],["x3","y3"],["x4","y4"]]
const coordenadasInvertidas = array1.map(item=> item.reverse())
```

Este código te modifica el coordenadas original también por el reverse y las referencias, por eso en el primer ejemplo hago una copia antes del array con spread operators y luego aplico el reverse, eso devuelve los valores invertidos sin afectar al coordenadas.

---

Por último también podrías hacer algo así, pero también modificaría al coordenadas original.

```
const coordenadas = [["x1","y1"],["x2","y2"],["x3","y3"],["x4","y4"]]
const array2 = array1.map(item=>[item[0], item[1]] = [item[1], item[0]])
```

Aquí se aplica algo llamado swap.

Comment: Lo que tengo es un string, no un array de strings:          
"[[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],[x4,y4],...,[xn,yn]]"